# Button Click Does Not Update SQL Server Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an `asp.net` app and I have a page where a user can change their password and I would and onclick of the 'Submit' button a success modal is displayed but my SQL Server table is not updated.

**View - Submit button**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnChangePassword" Text="Change Password" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="btnChangePassword_Click" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#placesModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"/>
```

**View - Modal close button**

```
<div class="modal-footer SuggestPlaceFooter">
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnClose" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Close" OnClick="btnClose_Click" data-dismiss="modal" ToolTip="Click to close this screen." />
</div>
```

**Code behind - Submit button `onclick`**

```
protected void btnChangePassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region Update 'Password' column in the 'Users' table
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
                        "UPDATE Users " +
                        "SET Password values('" + txtConfirmPassword + "') " +
                        "WHERE Username = " + Session["Username"] + " ", conn);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

**Code behind - Close button `onclick`**

```
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;
    txtConfirmPassword.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

**SQL table details**

Table name = Users

Column to update = Password

The update should obviously **ONLY** update for the use logged in which I thought I could use `Session["Username"]` as I am using this in other places as this name matches a `Username` column in SQL server.

Comment: You should be using parameters instead of strings to avoid injection attacks, especially since the value you are passing is a password.

Comment: What error/exception do you get?

Comment: Aren't you getting an exception, because your UPDATE query does not seem to be right.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I was due to all the modal stuff as it would not hit any breakpoint unless I removed it all and I also updated my `Update` statement to:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
                 "UPDATE Users " +
                 "SET Password ='" + txtConfirmPassword.Text + "' " +
                 "WHERE Username ='" + Session["Username"] + "' ", conn);
```

Comment: You're still open to sql injection

Comment: @Izzy No, i tried with all the modal HTML and it would not hit my breakpoint but as soon as i removed it all it did. So i moved it the SQL code to my 'Close' button on the modal which worked fine for me.  The SQL code was fine once i had it all working

Answer (score 4):

Your update query was wrong hence the column wasn't updating. Also your query was open to Sql Injection. I've changed your code accordingly and also used `using` block to ensure the connection object is closed and disposed correctly.

To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block. **[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

```
string password = txtConfirmPassword;
var userName = Session["Username"];
string myQuery = "UPDATE Users SET Password = @password Where Username = @username";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connection))
  {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = password;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
     connection.Open();

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
} //connection closed and disposed here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL command should be like this:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
                        "UPDATE Users " +
                        "SET Password = '" + txtConfirmPassword.Text + "' " +
                        "WHERE Username = " + Session["Username"] + " ", conn);
```

Have a look here: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/update.php

**EDIT**: Or better, your query should use parameters to avoid [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) like this:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
                        "UPDATE Users " +
                        "SET Password = @password" + 
                        "WHERE Username = @username ;" , conn);
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtConfirmPassword.Text);
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session["Username"].ToString());
```

Here can you find a basic example of a prepared UPDATE command:
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parametrized_SQL_statement#C.23

Comment: To OP: Please **do use** prepared statements -- SQL injection attacks are a very really issue. NEDian, you may want to include a sample that uses prepared statements, offering that as the answer.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Yeah, exactly. I am looking for an example.